# How To Access/Call Alert AlertDialog Box from static method in to My Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

This is my class:

```
public class UTILS
{
    public static void  AlertssDialogBox(Context context,String Message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog2.setMessage(Message);
        alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

            }
         }); 

        alertDialog2.show();
    }   
}
```

In my activity I call the class and static method:

```
UTILS.AlertssDialogBox(getApplicationContext(),"Please Coonect Internet");
```

But it shows an error.

Comment: What error is it showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, It may be helpful for you.

```
public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message)
    {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // Handle your on click action
          } 
        }); 
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

And call this in your activity class:-

```
UTILS.alertDialogShow(YourActivity.this,"Your Error Message")
```

Comment: With this approach your onClick event is still not adaptable with the custom actions per dialog... say Activity 1 wants to redirect to some another activity using this confirmation (Positive or OK action) while Activity 2 want to lets say clear the shared preferences or something... how you would have done that.... :) Think.

Comment: Then you have to pass click listener instance into method param and have to set that instance on positive button.